# How can I show Growl notifications on both displays?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, growl

I've got a MacBook Pro connected to an external display. Right now the notifications come through on on the primary display (MacBook Pro built in display) and not the external display. I know I can change this so that it shows on the secondary display but not the primary, but I want the notifications to show on displays. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently there is no way to accomplish this. The Growl mailing lists [have discussed](http://groups.google.com/group/growldiscuss/browse_thread/thread/10cf3ba08b1cb658) allowing Growl to always place the notification on the display that you have a window focused in.

For example, you have 3 displays, oriented in a horizontal line, and you're doing some file management on the far-left display and web browsing on the far right. If Finder has focus, the notification will be shown on the far-left display, if Safari/Chrome/Firefox/$BROWSER has focus, the notification will be shown on the far-right display.

But this feature has not yet been implemented, so you are limited to explicitly configuring Growl to send notifications to a single display.

This feature has been written up on their Google Code Project page, so you can star [the issue](http://code.google.com/p/growl/issues/detail?id=122) in order to receive further notifications.

Note that you can star it on an issue detail page by clicking the star outline to the left of the title "Issue 122: [...]", or at the bottom of the page just above the comment box. After clicking the star in either location, it will turn yellow and have a thicker blue outline, that means you've subscribed, and in essence, "voted" for the feature.