# Can I display notifications on my non-primary monitor? Or on both displays?

Tags: display, notifications

This issue has [plagued Growl](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39927/how-can-i-show-growl-notifications-on-both-displays) for ages.  And ML's track record with multiple monitor support isn't great.

But it's worth asking: can I display notification center's badges or alerts on multiple displays, or on the non-primary display?  Plist tricks?

Answer (score 2):

In Growl perferences, under Displays you have a screen dropdown to choose with screen you want the notifications to appear on. The screenshot is from Growl 2.0.1.

[image: Screenshot]