# Chrome notifications not appearing on both monitors (dual monitor)?

Tags: display, google-chrome, notifications

When using Chrome notifications on OS X, how can I set the notifications to appear across two monitors simultaneously?

I'm using a Macbook Pro and a Thunderbolt Display, and Chrome notifications - for example, a notification of a new message on Meta Chat - only display on the Macbook Pro. I would like the notifications to display on both monitors.

I have tried:

- Going into the 'Settings' of Chrome Notifications, which only allows 
  users to change what sites can send them notifications.
- Apple's Notification Center looks to control Apple's native notifications, rather than Chrome notifications.

Comment: Do you have notifications of any kind, from any app/service, appearing on the secondary monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is currently not possible.**

Google Chrome uses its own code for displaying notifications which Keyboard Maestro doesn't seem to be able to interact with. There appears to be no AppleScript for even detecting notifications and Google Chrome seems to refuse to provide the content of the message to Keyboard Maestro for any sort of macro.

Also, sending Chrome notifications to Growl also doesn't help since Growl still can't show notifications on multiple displays:

- [How can I show Growl notifications on both displays?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39927/how-can-i-show-growl-notifications-on-both-displays)

Comment: @JoshHelfgott - if grgarside is willing to test my crazy new idea of [running multiple instances of Chrome](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130135/chrome-notifications-not-appearing-on-both-monitors-dual-monitor/131044#131044), perhaps we can put this question to bed and move on to even crazier ideas that require us to be yet even more Thinkier Differenter.

Comment: @chillin Will test tomorrow when I'm on my computer. (FYI your ping did not work as the user has not commented on this post)

Comment: appreciated… and thanks, hmm, foiled again. < _twists thin mustache_ >

Comment: Actually Growl can show Notifications on multiple screens with some Applescript tricky, Growl Action Script and a Theme assigned to each screen. But the only problem is getting apps to use growl instead of NC.

Answer (score 0):

### multiple Chrome instances with multiple profiles

I didn't originally specify, but the idea is you have one instance of Chrome running on one display, and another running on another, and you are logged into the same Google account from both. In theory, this should give you the exact functionality you want. You should be able to close all the windows of one of the instances, and hide the application, and still see the notifications pop up (if the notifications steal focus).

---

Open up /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app

type at the prompt

```
josh2note@stack:~$
josh2note@stack:~$ 
josh2note@stack:~$ mkdir Chrome\ Profile\ Secondary
josh2note@stack:~$ /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=Chrome\ Profile\ Secondary &
josh2note@stack:~$
josh2note@stack:~$
```

Drag the Chrome window that appears to your secondary display. Log into your Google account.

Go back to the terminal.

type at the prompt

```
josh2note@stack:~$
josh2note@stack:~$
josh2note@stack:~$ 
josh2note@stack:~$ mkdir Chrome\ Profile\ Main
josh2note@stack:~$ /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=Chrome\ Profile\ Main &
josh2note@stack:~$
```

Leave the Chrome window that appears on the main display and log into the same Google account.

Comment: I bet this works. Any one else willing to test this? I cannot. Thanks.

Comment: Tested this in a few different ways and as much as I thought this'd work, it doesn't seem to :( Pure speculation: one of the Chromes shows the notification and causes it to be marked as read which means the other Chrome doesn't need to display it?

Comment: @grgarside - very appreciated. If you think of any other way to test this idea, at your liesure and convenience, please have at it. I was soooo hoping this would work.     :'(

Answer (score -1):

## [video Mirroring](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5019)

> Mirroring displays the same image on each display.
>
> - 1) Make sure your additional display is properly connected and powered on.
> - 2) From the Apple () menu, choose System Preferences.
> - 3) From the View menu, choose Displays.
> - 4) Click the Arrangement tab.
> - 5) Enable (check) "Mirror Displays" in the bottom-left corner.
>
> In the example below. the blue boxes represent each display that is connected. The white bar at the top of both boxes represents your menu bar and is shown on both displays when they are showing the same information.
>
> [image: Display Prefs]

Comment: Yes that's a good way, but it also mirrors everything he does not want :D

Comment: @YoshiBotX : From the question as asked, that is unclear.

Comment: That is right. And it is a Solution I support. But I am pretty sure, that If he uses Multiple Displays, he wants individual Screens with mirrored notifications.

Comment: I can't assume that, until he states it explicitly.

Comment: You've assumed the opposite; if you're unsure of something you should ask as a comment, not post an inappropriate answer.

Answer (score -1):

From experience I know that developers are very accomodating.

If you want this feature, you should, and get all your friends also to, go to register and request this feature at the [Google Chrome Bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list). You'd be surprised how well that works.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but that doesn't look like the official feature request forum…?

Comment: @grgarside - I could not find another one, so that is it. I don't understand how you got all 150 pts for your answer... doesn't seem fair, does it?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list would be the right place.